# Vue, edit the content of components with another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple Vue js spa app that contain some bulma.io component.
And I need to edit the content of components with another component.

Like this image:

[image: Some bulma.io component]

And somehow we need it to dynamically show form component when the panel or message component is clicked.

Thanks

Updated:

index.html

```
<div id="app">

    <div class="columns">

      <div class="column is-6">

        <message title="Message test title 1" body="Message test body 1" @titleUpdate="title = $event" @bodyUpdate="body = $event"></message>
        <message title="Message test title 2" body="Message test body 2" @titleUpdate="title = $event" @bodyUpdate="body = $event"></message>

        <card title="Card test title 1" body="Card test body 2" @titleUpdate="title = $event" @bodyUpdate="body = $event"></card>
        <card title="Card test title 1" body="Card test body 2" @titleUpdate="title = $event" @bodyUpdate="body = $event"></card>

      </div>

      <div class="column is-6">

        <messageform></messageform>

        <cardform></cardform>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import message from './components/message'
import card from './components/card'
import messageform from './components/messageform'
import cardform from './components/cardform'

/* eslint-disable */

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { message, card, messageform, cardform }
});
```

card.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <figure class="image is-4by3">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
          <figure class="image is-48x48">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="Placeholder image">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="media-content">
          <p class="title is-4">{{ title }}</p>
          <p class="subtitle is-6">@{{ title }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        {{ body }}
        <br>
        <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title', 'body'],
  name: 'card',
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.card {
  margin-top: 20px
}
</style>
```

message.vue

```
<template>
  <article class="message" v-show="isShow">
    <div class="message-header">
      <p>{{ title }}</p>
      <button class="delete" aria-label="delete" @click="close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="message-body">
      {{ body }}
    </div>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title', 'body'],
  name: 'message',
  data () {
    return {
      isShow: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close () {
      this.isShow = false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

cardform.vue

```
<template>
  <article>

    <h1>Card form</h1>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Card title</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" :value="title">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Card body</label>
      <div class="control">
        <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Textarea" :value="body"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title', 'body'],
  name: 'cardform'
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

messgeform.vue

```
<template>
  <article>

    <h1>Message form</h1>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Message title</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" :value="title" @input="titleUpdate">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Message body</label>
      <div class="control">
        <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Textarea" :value="body" @input="bodyUpdate"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title', 'body'],
  name: 'messageform',
  methods: {
    titleUpdate (event) {
      this.$emit('titleUpdate', event.target.value)
    },
    bodyUpdate (event) {
      this.$emit('bodyUpdate', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should take a look at the usage of [Passing Data to Child Components with props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and [Sending Messages to Parents with Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events) as it will cover everything you need to know to implement that functionality.

When you want to pass data to child you'll need to use props and get the data back by using the event emitter.

You can use eventbus or even vuex. I suggest you to take a look at props and events first.

Comment: Thanks, but forget to mention that i'm new in vue.  

I know the base of component but i can't keep together all of these in a simple example :(  

If i have a simple example of described functionality i can extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understood your question, but [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) may help you if you want to transfer data/use fonction from one component to another.